# Google Calendar API: Timezone bug

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I am having a hard time figuring out why the Google calendar notifications always convert my event timings from the given timezone to the default timezone.

Here is my event data:

```
data = {
        'summary': booking.calendar_event_title,
        'description': booking.calendar_event_description,
        'start': {'dateTime': start_date, 'timeZone': booking.address.timezone},
        'end': {'dateTime': end_date, 'timeZone': booking.address.timezone},
        'location': booking.address.formatted_address,
        'attendees': [...],
    }
```

Here, the `start_date` and `end_date` are in (let's say) CDT format. I'm passing the correct `timeZone` value as well.

However, when I receive the calendar invite, It always shows time converted into the standard timezone (which is AEST in my case).

[image]

I don't know what is going on here. Please help.